# how can I use pystat parser

Tags: python

how can I use pystat parser:

```
import nltk
from stat_parser import Parser

parser = Parser()
print (parser.parse("How can the net amount of entropy of the universe be massively decreased?"))
```

error:

```
No module named 'stat_parser'
```

Comment: Did you actually install [pyStatParser](https://github.com/emilmont/pyStatParser)?

Answer (score 0):

The parser module has been depreciated now. For the majority of use cases, you can leverage the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) generation and compilation stage, using the ast module.

Comment: actually I want to generate parsed sentence from tagged sentence using nltk or stanford parser..but they all take raw sentence as an input